# Highlight when Table row clicked and disable on next row clicked

Tags: android, tablerow

I have a table row having multiple data. When a row is clicked, that particular row is highlighted with dark gray color. But when i click the next row, the clicked row is highlighted but the previous row is still highlighted. How do i disable the highlight of previous row. I tried many tricks, but that's not working.

This is my sample code.

```
tableRow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
           v.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);

}
```

I have created the layout programmatically. I am not using XML.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: see my new update u just need to add more `State` into `StateListDrawable` as per u r requirement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use the stock on click highlight like you get with a generic ListView, you want to set the background of each row to be

```
android:background="@drawable/selector"
```

Here is an example:

```
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:padding="5dip" 
    android:background="@drawable/selector">
```

This is `selector.xml` in `res\drawable` folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item   android:state_focused="true"
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@color/blue></item>
<item   android:state_focused="true"
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@color/custom"></item>
<item
        android:state_focused="false"
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@color/gray" />


 <item android:drawable="@color/white"></item>

</selector>
```

**Update:** Create `StateListDrawable` programmatically like below and set as `Background` to your `TableRow`:

```
 Drawable d1=activity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.gradient_bg_hover);

  GradientDrawable g = new GradientDrawable(Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM,
            new int[] { Color.DKGRAY});       
 g.setGradientType(GradientDrawable.LINEAR_GRADIENT);

            StateListDrawable states = new StateListDrawable();
            states.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_pressed,-android.R.attr.state_selected},d1);
            states.addState(new int[] {-android.R.attr.state_focused},g);

            table_row.setBackgroundDrawable(states);
```

This is `gradient_bg_hover.xml` in `res\drawable` folder .

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<!-- Gradient BgColor for listrow Selected -->
<gradient
  android:startColor="#18d7e5"
  android:centerColor="#16cedb"
  android:endColor="#09adb9"
  android:angle="270" />
</shape>
```

**Update2:** You can add More `State` to `StateListDrawable` as per your requirement.

1. `android:state_activated:` set when a view or its parent has been "activated" meaning the user has currently marked it as being of interest.
2. `android:state_active:` State value for `StateListDrawable`.
3. `android:state_enabled:` Set when a view is enabled.
4. `android:state_focused:` State value for `StateListDrawable`, set when a view has input focus.
5. `android:state_pressed:` set when the user is pressing down in a view.
6. `android:state_selected:` set when a view (or one of its parents) is currently selected.

More information about [StateListDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html)

Comment: I have created the layout programmatically. I am not using XML.

Comment: In every condition, it only highlight the last row.

Comment: it depends upon the data stored in database table.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46832/discussion-between-m-d-and-suniel)

Comment: I have uploaded 2 snapshots. The first one is after the clicked event and the second one is the initial state before click event.

Comment: I wouldn't say that is 'stock' on click.  You are defining your own colors.  How do you get the stock onclick with the default colors?